# How to groupby a key and return min/max values in other columns on a single row?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda, group-by

I have a set of data that I am trying to group together based on a common key in column A and I want it to return a single row of information per grouped key value. Grouping is easy, but I am having issues with my other columns returning the values that I need. Here is the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,6,4,5,5],
                   'B': [1.1,2.1,1.2,2.2,3.1,3.2,3.3,4.1,5.1,6.1,6.2,4.2,5.2,5.3],
                   'C':[10.1,20.1,10.1,20.1,30.1,30.1,30.1,40.1,50.1,60.1,60.1,40.1,50.1,50.1],
                   'D':['','',10.2,20.2,'','',30.2,'','','',60.2,40.2,'',50.2]
                   })

df
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    A   B   C       D
0   1   1.1 10.1    
1   2   2.1 20.1    
2   1   1.2 10.1    10.2
3   2   2.2 20.1    20.2
4   3   3.1 30.1    
5   3   3.2 30.1    
6   3   3.3 30.1    30.2
7   4   4.1 40.1    
8   5   5.1 50.1    
9   6   6.1 60.1    
10  6   6.2 60.1    60.2
11  4   4.2 40.1    40.2
12  5   5.2 50.1    
13  5   5.3 50.1    50.2
```

I want to group by column "A", have column "B" display the minimum value, and then column "D" return the maximum value. My **desired output** would look something like this:

```
    A   B   C       D
0   1   1.1 10.1    10.2
1   2   2.1 20.1    20.2
2   3   3.1 30.1    30.2
3   4   4.1 40.1    40.2
4   5   5.1 50.1    50.2
5   6   6.1 60.1    60.2
```

I have tried grouping by column "A" and then have column "B" only pull the minimum value for each grouped key and then display the remaining column values for that minimum value in column "B" in a single row, but it outputs the NaN values for column "D". Currently the output of the code looks like this:

```
df = df.loc[df.groupby('A')['B'].idxmin()]

df
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    A   B   C     D
0   1   1.1 10.1    
1   2   2.1 20.1    
4   3   3.1 30.1    
7   4   4.1 40.1    
8   5   5.1 50.1    
9   6   6.1 60.1
```

I also tried using groupby with lambda and ffill().tail(1), and got the result I wanted for column "D" but column "B" isn't the minimum/lowest value. Here is the code and output for that:

```
out = df.replace({'': pd.NA}) \
        .groupby("A", as_index=False) \
        .apply(lambda x: x.ffill().tail(1)) \
        .reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
df = out
df
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    A   B   C       D
2   1   1.2 10.1    10.2
3   2   2.2 20.1    20.2
6   3   3.3 30.1    30.2
11  4   4.2 40.1    40.2
13  5   5.3 50.1    50.2
10  6   6.2 60.1    60.2
```

Any ideas how I can combine these two pieces of code to make it so that I get the minimum value in column "A" and the maximum value in column "B" all within the same row based on the common key value.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should consider: `df.replace({'':float('nan')}).groupby('A').agg({'B':min, 'C':'first', 'D':max})`

Comment: @Onyambu my real dataset I use datetime in both columns C and D and those are what need to be min and maxed. I failed to mention this in the post because I didn't believe it would impact much, but I am getting a TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances or 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'. Do i need to change my datetime to another dtype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try via `replace()` method:

```
df['D']=df['D'].replace('| ',float('NaN'),regex=True)
#replace the '' or ' ' to NaN
```

Finally use `groupby()` and `agg()`:

```
out=df.groupby('A',as_index=False).agg({'B':'min','C':'first','D':'max'})
#use groupby and agg your according to your need
```

output of `out`:

```
    A   B       C       D
0   1   1.1     10.1    10.2
1   2   2.1     20.1    20.2
2   3   3.1     30.1    30.2
3   4   4.1     40.1    40.2
4   5   5.1     50.1    50.2
5   6   6.1     60.1    60.2
```

Comment: Let say my actual dataset contains datetimes in columns C and D. I could pass 'first' in place of 'min' in column B and 'last' in place of 'max' in column D right? Also if I had several more columns that I want included at the end of the new df from the original, is there a way to pass the additional column names into the code so that they will display as well? Or do I need to perform a merge operation on the original df with the additional columns I want pulled out into a new df and the groupby dataframe from that is created by your code?

Comment: @jonny_two_knives yes you could pass 'first' in place of 'min' in column B and 'last' in place of 'max' in column D right and if there are more columns that you want to include then you can agg them according to your need or after aggregrating `A,B,C,D` merge them on `['A','B','C','D']` i.e `out.merge(df,on=['A','B','C','D'])`